# What is a purpose of big file with strange name in home/[username] directory?

Tags: linux-mint

In my user home directory I have a file named:

> tmp1HUvJk
>   WglW1PwW_XpIMt9TjXEQlg_j_RFl2FAc2Dwk-.vwYAjVaOcbRikPg5_BjfAevak9jdzmZSnIj6l5HkjAZ5cmA94pMRso1biw19qyrZ8jhkW5pG9KxjSI
>   vC
>   QK2qS5Mbt-4H3za0OVLRCgUurAwZjfGh1gLoNJ06AnrHGEa6FMGSvq4XzlMyQYx7k.6FkGqL-e1
>   TWhWFjF2SggniWkaln57EhuBiMI2HuVwIj.CHzaRJcgKLwqZ

The file size is 13GB

What is the purpose of this file?

Comment: looks like garbage to me! :)  you can run `file` on it to see if it might contain anything useful. also: `od -c tmp1H* | head` to see if you recognize anything in it.

Comment: The file is a temporary file made by a process that you ran. Does this file actually have newlines in the file name?

Comment: @fd0, a 13 GiB temporary file is very strange. I'd check if the filesystem is somehow corrupt (`fsck(8)` or such).

Comment: Is that the actual file name or did you omit some unprintable characters? Having only letters, a few punctuation signs, *and newlines* is a strange combination. Is the file still open? `lsof /path/to/file`

Comment: @Gilles lsof gives me nothing at output.

Comment: @JeffSchaller file command gives me 'data' at output

Comment: @fd0 yes, file name have new lines

Comment: My best guess is that it's broken output from someone trying to create random data in a temporary file (the prefix of "tmp" is suspicious).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information from the comments, I'm going to guess that the file is useless. Try renaming it for a period of time and see if anything breaks that you care about. `mv tmp1HUvJk* delete_me`. If nothing breaks, then remove it altogether-- `rm delete_me`.

Comment: Done it. Seems to be ok and file wasn't created.